# How to run a Java Script function and get return in Android?

Tags: javascript, c#, android, xamarin

I'm working on a project in Xamarin C# and I'm having trouble running  some Java Script. Is there currently a way to call a specific JS function and receive its return value?

I know that JS can be run in a WebView; however, how can I get the output?

At the moment, the JS is coming from a link on my site. Any help would be very much appreciated!

---

### **EDIT**

Here's the code I've tried:

**MyView.axml**

```
 <android.webkit.WebView
            android:id="@+id/web_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            local:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pause"
            local:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

**MyView.cs**

called in `protected override void OnCreate`

```
webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
webView.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
webView.LoadUrl("http://www.example.com/scheduleV5.js");
```

**MyWebViewClient (class)**

```
public class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient
{
    public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
    {
        view.EvaluateJavascript("javascript: getSchedule();", new EvaluateBack());
    }
}
```

**EvaluateBack (class)**

```
public class EvaluateBack : Java.Lang.Object, IValueCallback
{

    public void OnReceiveValue(Java.Lang.Object value)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(Android.App.Application.Context, value.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();// you will get the value "100"
        var test = value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see [How to pass data to WebView Javascript and back](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/100808/how-pass-data-to-webview-javascript-and-back) or [Xamarin Forms WebView Executing JavaScript](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-webview-executing-javascript/)

Comment: could it work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could do like this

**Js calls methods in C#**

Configure the OnCreate method in the Activity :

```
var webview = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);
WebSettings settings = webview.Settings;
settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
// load the javascript interface method to call the foreground method
webView.AddJavascriptInterface(new MyJSInterface(this), "CSharp");
webview.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Create a C# class ：

```
class MyJSInterface : Java.Lang.Object
  {
    Context context;

  public MyJSInterface (Context context)
    {
      this.context = context;
    }

  [JavascriptInterface]
  [Export]
  public void ShowToast (string msg)
    {
      Toast.MakeText(context, msg, ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
  }
```

And then it's called in JS ：

```
<button type="button" onClick="CSharp.ShowToast ('Call C#')">Call C#</button>
```

You can refer to this document：https://github.com/xamarin/recipes/tree/master/Recipes/android/controls/webview/call_csharp_from_javascript

**C# calls a method in JS and gets the callback value**

```
webView.EvaluateJavascript("javascript: callJS();", new EvaluateBack());

class EvaluateBack : Java.Lang.Object,IValueCallback
    {

        public void OnReceiveValue(Object value)
        {

            Toast.MakeText(Android.App.Application.Context, value.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();// you will get the value "100"
        }
    }
```

in JS :

```
<script>
      function callJS(){
        return 100;
      }
</script>
```

Comment: could it help you ?

Comment: I might be a little confused, do you want to call the JS method in C# and get the callback value? If so, please refer to the second method I updated

Comment: Perfect! the second method is what I'm looking for. I'll try it out and let you know.

Comment: I keep getting a null return value. Just to clarify I call:  `webView.LoadUrl("http://mywebsite.com/file.js"); `  then evaluatescript?

Comment: You could customize a "WebViewClient" and then call "webview.evaluatescript" in "OnPageFinished"

Comment: Still getting null... will update post with some code I’ve tried tomorrow.

Comment: Fixed it! Had to use a link to the html page where the java script was being utilized, instead of a direct link to the file. Thanks for all your help!