# Cannot open Gallary or file manager from WebView Android

Tags: android, webview, xamarin.android

Hi I am loading an external web page to my `WebView`. That web page has an upload pdf and upload image buttons. But When I click on these buttons it doesn't open the gallery or documents.

This is my code

```
        _webView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webview);


        _webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        _webView.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
        _webView.Settings.DatabaseEnabled = true;
        _webView.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
        _webView.Settings.AllowContentAccess = true;
        _webView.SetWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
        _webView.SetWebChromeClient(new CustomChromeClient());

public class CustomChromeClient : WebChromeClient
{
    public override void OnPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request)
    {
        request.Grant(request.GetResources());
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this? Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: ,Please confirm whether you have associated the Button OnClick  in the Webview with the method in C#, here is the help link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54067402/how-to-run-a-java-script-function-and-get-return-in-android/54069075#54069075

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly ask the android system to launch an intent to choose a file. 
The following page should tell you how to request all sorts of media types. Mainly I think you want file chooser.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider#java