# downloading url that starts with "blob:" in webview MAUI

Tags: c#, url, download, blob, maui

I am trying to download some files from my MAUI application. Application is built on a webView from where files should be downloaded. I have this logic in my DownloadListner:

```
 public class CustomDownloadListener : Java.Lang.Object, IDownloadListener
 {
  
     public async void OnDownloadStart(string url, string userAgent, string contentDisposition, string mimetype, long contentLength)
     {
            try
            {
                
                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(global::Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url.Replace("blob:", "")));
                    
                    request.SetMimeType(mimetype);
                    request.SetNotificationVisibility(DownloadVisibility.VisibleNotifyCompleted);

                    // if this path is not create, we can create it.  
                    string thmblibrary = FileSystem.AppDataDirectory + "/download";
                    if (!Directory.Exists(thmblibrary))
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(thmblibrary);

                    request.SetDestinationInExternalFilesDir(global::Android.App.Application.Context, FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "download");
                    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager)global::Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(global::Android.App.Application.DownloadService);
                    dm.Enqueue(request);
            }
            catch(Exeption ex)
            {
            }
      }
      
}
```

this works well for transferring most of the files in the app, but if the URL starts with the "**blob:https://...**" DownloadManager will throw an exception. I also tried to remove "**blob:**" from the URL in this case, the file gets downloaded but it is corrupted.

Is there any other way to transfer those files?

Comment: `blob:` URIs are created in the browser by `URL.createObjectURL` from a client-side `Blob` or `File` object - you can "download" it by doing `const a = new HTMLAnchorElement(); a.href = blobUri; a.click();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the limit in the android webview.

> Android DownloadManager is designated for downloading remote files using HTTP / HTTPS protocols only. A blob is not a remote data, but something within your WebView. So the workaround is to convert the Blob into Base64 string and write it to a file.

You can refer to the case about [Unable to download Blob file type in WebView on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53647087/unable-to-download-blob-file-type-in-webview-on-android) and the case about [Download Blob file from Website inside Android WebViewClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48892390/download-blob-file-from-website-inside-android-webviewclient).

In addition, you can refer to this case about [how to use JavaScriptInterface in the xamarin.android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58739703/javascriptinterface-in-xamarin-android-is-obsolete-and-cant-invoke-c-sharp-from) and t[his answer about using JavaScriptInterface in the maui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73305801/17455524).