# How do I handle results from Control.EvaluateJavascript in xamarin?

Tags: javascript, c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I know how to call js-functions with the Android.Webkit as long as I dont have to handle a return-value:

```
 Control.EvaluateJavascript("removeAllPins()", null);
```

But I dont know how to call a function that returns a function? The function takes an object of IValueCallback as a paramter but I can't create an instance of it because it's an interface and not a class.
How do I get the result of a js-function thats called in Android with EvaluateJavascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do in your webview renderer like below ,refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54069075/10768653):

```
Control.EvaluateJavascript("javascript: removeAllPins();", new EvaluateBack());

class EvaluateBack : Java.Lang.Object,IValueCallback
  {

      public void OnReceiveValue(Object value)
      {

        Toast.MakeText(Android.App.Application.Context, value.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();// you will get the value you want to return.
      }
   }
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thanks, but why does this return the value 100?

Comment: @actopozipc my mistake,this is in my project.

Answer (score 0):

maybe:

```
Control.EvaluateJavascript("removeAllPins()", null, new gitGud());
```

Comment: Mind to explain why this would help?